# SQL Server fulltext_semantic_languages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

When trying to install [a semantic search example](https://web.archive.org/web/20151226151016/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlfts/archive/2011/07/21/introducing-fulltext-statistical-semantic-search-in-sql-server-codename-denali-release.aspx), I'm running into a problem.

There are some steps in the example to check if the 'new' Semantic Search and Full Text Search are installed.

Executing the following T-SQL code returns the version '11.0.1153.1.1' of the semantic database.

```
/* Verify the registration is succeeded */
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_semantic_language_statistics_database;
GO
```

And...the following T-SQL code returns 1, which indicates that Full-Text Search and Semantic Search are installed.

```
/* Check if Full-Text Search and Semantic Search are installed*/
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled');
GO
```

I also registered the 'language_statistics_db'.

```
/* Register Language Statistics Database */
EXEC sp_fulltext_semantic_register_language_statistics_db 'semanticsdb';
GO
```

I'm executing the following T-SQL code to verify if the languages are installed correctly *(this is were something odd happens)*.

```
/* Check available languages for statistical semantic extraction */
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_semantic_languages;
GO
```

This statement returns no rows, indicating that there are no languages installed. I tried reinstalling the database(s) but with no effect.

Can someone point out to me were I made a mistake?

**UPDATE**: After unregistering the semantic_language database and registering it using 'master' it worked. No idea why this worked. ***Why? Someone?***

The code that worked for me:

```
/ * Unregistar language db */ 
EXEC sp_fulltext_semantic_unregister_language_statistics_db
GO
```

And registering:

```
/ * register_language db */ 
Use master
EXEC sp_fulltext_semantic_register_language_statistics_db
GO
```